# Need guidance to backup files from a non-started imac

Tags: macos, macos-high-sierra

My iMac cannot boot. Apple Store did a lot of hardware checks but cannot find anything wrong. They can boot it using external drive though. They recommend to format the disk and reinstall the OS.

I'd like to back up files (photos, documents, etc) before doing reinstall. Can I have your guidance? Questions:

1. If I boot iMac using a external disk (or USB), can I copy the files then?
2. If so, how can I create such bootable disk or USB?

Really appreciate...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I later found I don't need to create a bootable disk or USB. I followed [Create a disk image](https://support.apple.com/guide/disk-utility/create-a-disk-image-dskutl11888/mac) in [Disk Utility Help](https://support.apple.com/guide/disk-utility/welcome/mac), and backed up everything under /Users to an external drive.

Looks like in creating disk image, 'compressed' option takes much longer time than 'read only'.